# python for loop insert number from range

Tags: python, for-loop, format, range

I'm trying to scrape a web page with pagination.

Code:

```
from requests_html import _URL, HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1,6):
    s = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop'
    url += '&page={}'
    r=s.get(url.format(page))
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}
```

Expectation:

```
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={1}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={2}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={3}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={4}
https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={5}
```

I'm still new and learning python, please help me to get the my expected result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not modifying `url`, only the string sent to `get()`. Try `url = url.format(page)`, this will give you `https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page=1`

Comment: You're correctly using `url.format(page)` to interpolate the number into the placeholder. And you're passing that formatted URL to `s.get` correctly. But that doesn't modify the unformatted `url` variable, when you're then printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url doesn't get modified, try:

```
from requests_html import _URL, HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1,6):
    s = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop'
    url += '&page={}'
    url = url.format(page)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(url)
```

Or even better:

```
from requests_html import _URL, HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for page in range(1,6):
    s = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={}'.format(page)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your python version supports f strings...

```
from requests_html import _URL, HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1,6):
    s = HTMLSession()
    url = f'https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=laptop&page={page}'
    r = s.get(url)
    print(url)
```